# Is there any way to implicitly construct a type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, types

I read of a useful trick about how you can avoid using the wrong domain data in your code by creating a data type for each domain type you're using. By doing this the compiler will prevent you from accidentally mixing your types.

For example, defining these:

```
public struct Meter
{
    public int Value;

    public Meter(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public struct Second
{
    public int Value;

    public Second(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

allows me to not mix up meters and seconds because they're separate data types. This is great and I can see how useful it can be. I'm aware you'd still need to define operator overloads to handle any kind of arithmetic with these types, but I'm leaving that out for simplicity.

The problem I'm having with this approach is that in order to use these types I need to use the full constructor every time, like this:

```
Meter distance = new Meter(5);
```

Is there any way in C# I can use the same mode of construction that a `System.Int32` uses, like this:

```
Meter distance = 5;
```

I tried creating an implicit conversion but it seems this would need to be part of the Int32 type, not my custom types. I can't add an Extension Method to Int32 because it would need to be static, so is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean you can't add an extension method to `Int32` because it would be static?  (the whole point of extension methods is that they operate as though they are instance methods, which is perfectly applicable to primitives such as ints.)

Comment: I thought I needed to add the implicit operator converstion as a static method to Int32 but you can't add static methods to existing types (only instance methods.) Anyway, Kendal Frey got the right answer I was looking for.

Comment: I agree that's the answer you were looking for.  But I still don't understand what you mean by "static methods".  Extension methods for all intents and purposes act like instance methods.  So, for the sake of discussion, `Meter distance = 5.ToMeter();` would have worked just fine.  (though I agree it's not as concise as implicit conversions)

Comment: @Kirk: Extension methods behave as instance methods, but conversion operators must be static. This is why extension methods don't work.

Comment: @KendallFrey, yes, of course extension methods are not the same as implicit conversions.  In fact, the concept of using extension methods to achieve the *exact* same syntax as implicit conversions is silly.  But the fact remains that you *can* use extension methods to accomplish a similar goal.

Comment: What I mean is, how would I add a static method to Int32? For example, say I'm trying to add a method to Int32 that is Int32.DoSomething() . The reason I was looking at that was because I thought I needed to add the public static implicit operator Int32(Meter a) method there instead of to my own class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can specify an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) directly in the structs themselves.

```
public struct Meter
{
    public int Value;

    public Meter(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Meter(int a)
    {
         return new Meter(a);
    }
}

public struct Second
{
    public int Value;

    public Second(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Second(int a)
    {
         return new Second(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried an implicit operator as int(Meter m), don't know why I didn't try it the other way around. Wow. Thanks!